# Help me understand this reference from the footer of Stack Overflow in 2008

Tags: discussion, footer

I just browsed [the earliest save of Skeet's profile on web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20080929161340/https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (back when he only had 778 rep, unbelievable), when a line of text in the footer caught my eye:

> Using this website may cause [irreversible damage to the kidneys and liver.](https://web.archive.org/web/20080929161340/http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UM64dMoweio)

[image: screenshot of the footer]

The link is pointing to a long-gone video (it was taken down by Viacom back in 2008).

Please help me understand this reference. What was the video that this text was pointing to?

Comment: Googling the term turns up that it is at least a South Park reference. As in: probably a bit of humor.

Comment: I found a link to the same dead video and looks like it might have been the "Weight Gain 4000" episode - probably a joke about spending too much time on SO and not exercising.

Comment: All I can say is that some people clearly have too much time on their hands.  Go answer a real question :-)

Comment: [*Those early days must have been filled with a lot of humor: Using this website may cause irreversible damage to the kidneys and liver.*](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/795781)

Comment: [*The site also had an interesting disclaimer at the bottom of the page: Using this website may cause irreversible damage to the kidneys and liver.*](https://www.quora.com/What-did-the-first-version-of-Stack-Overflow-look-like)

Comment: that's crazy that was the day i joined the beta.

Comment: Am I reading this right? Jon had answered 31 questions gaining 778 reputation 3 days after he joined SO?

Comment: @Phonolog Don't forget that Jon Skeet is, well... Jon Skeet.

Comment: @the4kman Yeah right...

Comment: Even though I had a bit more a month later (https://web.archive.org/web/20081103104801/http://stackoverflow.com:80/users/6309/vonc), I actually had 775 rep total up to that day (end of Sept. 2018)... after 15 days on the site.

Comment: In Jon's archived profile, check the second answer in the "Answers" list entitled *What Easter Eggs have you placed in code?*, go to the bottom of the answer there is a link to a image of [Jon in Pyjamas](http://jonskeet.uk/pics/pyjamas.jpg)(the image link is still up!!).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Jeff was always known for having a sense of humour. While the YouTube link is long gone, it almost certainly linked to this:

[image: South Park "Weight Gain 4000" snippet]

It's the [South Park *Weight Gain 4000* episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_Gain_4000), one of Jeff's favourite shows.

The site also featured imagery from the [Flights of the Conchords series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords_(TV_series)), every time you are [asked to fill in the Google Captcha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/who-are-the-robots-in-the-captcha-request):

[image: Flights of the Conchords characters in robot outfits]

Flights of the Concords is [Jeff's favourite two man novelty band](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/02/podcast-12/).

Comment: There is a low-grade copy of the SP episode on [DailyMotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x62127x) (a site not known for pro-actively removing copyrighted content, I have the impression).

Comment: It's also available on [the official website of South Park Studios](http://www.southparkstudios.nu/full-episodes/s01e02-weight-gain-4000), although it's not available in all countries.

Comment: @the4kman: that'd be http://www.southparkstudios.co.uk/full-episodes/s01e02-weight-gain-4000 for me in the UK, and it fails to load.

Comment: I had to explicitly enable Flash and disable tracking protection for the video to start loading. The scene in question is at minute 07:02 and is essentially an ad for “Weight Gain 4000”. You can also check [the script for the episode](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Weight_Gain_4000/Script); the opening line for the scene is *“We'll be right back to Jesus and Pals, after this.”*